# Cannot edit images in wordpress 3.8.1 in backend

Tags: wordpress, image, rotation

I cannot edit (crop, rotate, scale, ...) images in the back-end of WordPress, on my local machine with Apache it works fine. I checked the permissions of the image, they are set to 777.

Is there a library which I need to install on the webserver?

My WordPress version is 3.8.1.

Comment: I would suggest for you to contact your hosting provider. They should be able to assist you and if needed load the library you need

Answer (score 1):

There was some problems in the functions.php file. Next was that the rotating did not work and this was because the php imagerotate() function was not supported, the GD version on the server was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Number 1:
Most of time this problem cause because of some unhealthy plugins in your WordPress website so I suggest you first deactivate all plugins of your WordPress website and then try to edit your WordPress images I hope you will find your problem solved....

Solution Number 2:
In admin, /wp-admin/options-media.php, it will ask you where you want WordPress to upload media files. Make sure you have it set to 'wp-content/uploads', NOT '/wp-content/uploads'.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the plugins are healthy and i could not find the lines in the options-media.php. But i don't thinks its a wordpress code problem because it works fine on my local apache server. i will check it out with my provider

Answer (score -1):

Open PHP GD extension in php.ini

php_gd2.dll
php_gd.dll